# Cargar combobox mediante otro combobox pero con string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-forms, combobox

*buenas, tengo un dilema que me ha dejado perplejo. La cuestión es que debo cargar un `ComboBox` con las provincias, hasta ahí todo va bien. Pero, el problema es que a partir de ese `ComboBox` se debe cargar otro `ComboBox` con los nombre de **asesores** que estén en la provincia que se eligió del `ComboBox`. Cargar las provincias no ha sido un problema, pero estoy cargando los datos desde una vista en `SQL Server` a la cual no puedo modificar y en la cual no existe un **ID**. Entonces, mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo cargar y filtrar mis asesores del segundo `ComboBox` utilizadon el primero.

Clase **ConexionSQL**:

```
    public List<Provincias> provinciasVista() //método para las provincias
    {
        List<Provincias> salida = new List<Provincias>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT provincia FROM V_SolicitudWeb GROUP BY provincia";
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"].ToString();
                        Provincias p = new Provincias(provincia);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }                
        }
    }


    public List<Personas> asesoresVista(string valor)//método para cargar los asesores
    {
        List<Personas> salida = new List<Personas>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(BD))
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT asesor " +
                "FROM V_SolicitudWeb " + 
                "WHERE provincia = @prov " + 
                "GROUP BY asesor";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prov", valor);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string nombre = dr["ASESOR"].ToString();
                        Personas p = new Personas(nombre);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                    return salida;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Formulario:

```
    private void menu1item1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmbProvincias.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cmbAsesor.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cmbProvincias.SelectedIndex = -1;
        llenarProvincias();
        llenarAsesores();
    }

    private void llenarProvincias()
    {
        ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
        cmbProvincias.DisplayMember = "provincia";
        cmbProvincias.DataSource = conexionSQL.provinciasVista();
    }

    private void llenarAsesores()
    {
        string valorSeleccionado = cmbProvincias.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (valorSeleccionado != "")
        {
            ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
            cmbAsesor.DisplayMember = "ASESOR";
            cmbAsesor.DataSource = conexionSQL.asesoresVista(valorSeleccionado);
        }
    }

    private void cmbProvincias_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        llenarAsesores();
    }
```

Las provincias si me cargan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el asesor no:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Veo que te falta la propiedad `ValueMember` de `cmbProvincias`, con lo que posiblemente cuando tratas de acceder a `SelectedValue` te este devolviendo algo que no esperas. Depura de todas maneras para ver que hay en `SelectedValue` cuando selecciones un valor

Comment: Tenías razón, me comí el `ValueMember` ¿Podrías poner la respuesta así la acepto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te falta la propiedad `ValueMember` de `cmbProvincias`, con lo que posiblemente cuando tratas de acceder a `SelectedValue` te este devolviendo algo que no esperas.

```
private void llenarProvincias()
{
    ConexionSQL conexionSQL = new ConexionSQL();
    cmbProvincias.DisplayMember = "provincia";
    cmbProvincias.ValueMember = "provincia";
    cmbProvincias.DataSource = conexionSQL.provinciasVista();
}
```